# Custom Element Factory

Tags: zend-framework-3

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь настроить фабрику для своего элемента формы, но не работает. Элемент задан в аннотациях формы. В конфиге прописано должно быть назначение фабрики для элемента, но ничего не подхватывает. Не срабатывает временная заглушка в виде Exception.
Я пытаюсь это сделать, чтобы потом можно было реализовать свой render для выбранного элемента.

```
### Entity

namespace Application;
...
use Zend\Form\Annotation;
...
class SomeEntity
{
...
/**
 * @Annotation\Type("Application\Form\Element\CustomElement")
 */
public $custom;
...
}

### module.config.php

...
'form_elements' => [
    'factories' => [
        \Application\Form\Element\CustomElement::class => function () {
            throw new \Exception('It works? No!');
        },
    ],
],
...

### IndexController 

function indexAction()
{
...
    $class = $this->params()->fromQuery('entity');
    $b = new AnnotationBuilder($this->getObjectManager());
    $form = $b->createForm($class);
...
}

### CustomElement

namespace Application\Form\Element;

use Zend\Form\Element;

class CustomElement extends Element
{
}
```

Comment: http://devblog.x2k.co.uk/using-custom-form-elements-with-the-annotationbuilder-in-zend-framework-2/